# Search for parentheses via ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a requirement where i need to index some text that is prefixed with (std) which i should then be able to search for again.

Ie. a document (html) contains the following sentence

> (std)Almindelige betingelser for misligholdelseserstatning

and i should be able to query for

> (std)Almindelige betingelser

Now, i've read a whole lot in the documentations and have now a charfilter in place which replaces ( and ) with _, and i thought i would then be safe to just to a replace in the search-query as well, so it becomes

> _std_Almindelige betingelser

but for some reason its simply not working AT ALL. No result at all is being returned when searching for `_std_Almindelige betingelser` even though i can see the term is there by browsing the document and return a list of facets.

This is my index settings and type mapping

```
var settings = new IndexSettings();

settings.Analysis.CharFilters.Add("parenthesis", new MappingCharFilter
{
    Mappings = new[] { "( => _", ") => _" }
});

settings.Analysis.TokenFilters.Add("snowball", new SnowballTokenFilter
{
    Language = "Danish"
});

settings.Analysis.Analyzers.Add("content", new CustomAnalyzer
{
    CharFilter = new List<string>() { "html_strip", "parenthesis" },
    Tokenizer = "whitespace",
    Filter = new List<string>() { "lowercase", "snowball" }
});
```

And the mapping

```
{"searchservicepages":{
    "_source":{
        "excludes" : ["content"]
    },
    "properties":{
        "content":{
            "type":"string",
            "index_analyzer"":"content"
        }
    }
}}
```

Comment: I would suggest to have a look at the [analyze api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/admin-indices-analyze/) and play around with it a little to see how you are analysing your text and what tokens you are indexing. I'm sure you'll then understand a lot more about what is happening to your data and what is best to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the mapping. 
You should change `"index_analyzer": "content"` into `"analyzer":"your_analyzer_name"`

While your mapping is giving me trouble, with same index settings following mapping worked fine.

```
  "testindex": {
        "testdoc": {
          "_source": {
            "excludes": [
              "content"
            ]
          },
          "properties": {
            "content": {
              "type": "string",
              "analyzer": "myAnalyzer"
            }
          }
        }
```

*Btw I'm using ES 0.90.2*

Comment: content IS my custom analyzer, which is using html_strip and parenthesis as CharFilters, whitespace as Tokenizer and lowercase and snowball as Filter. parenthesis is my custom CharFilter that should change ( and ) to _.

Comment: try to change left side of the code. `index_analyzer` to `analyzer`

Comment: You we're right, that was it. I know its a long time a go and i'm guilty of forgetting feedback when things work and you're moving on.